# How do I separate input with "..." in python?

Tags: python, input

Why do I need to add `*` before the variable?

I'm learning to code and I've just started, I attempted to use the code...

```
text = input().split(" ")
// to get users input text, where there are spaces and split it
print(*text, sep= "...")
// to print the text and use "..." as separators
```

I've tried a few things and this seems to be working well but I have a question as to why it only works when I used the asterisk before calling text? Also if there's any suggestion or things I may be doing wrong or could better that would help.

Comment: Try doing it without the `*` and see what the result looks like.

Comment: I inputed "is this thing working" and it returned this "['is', 'this', 'thing', 'working']", the question seems to have already been answered on another post so i'll work on understanding that post's answer

Comment: Without the `*` it prints the list. With the `*` it spreads the list into separate arguments, as if you'd written `print(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3], sep="...")`.

Comment: Thank you so much for that it helped me understand things alot better!